# Centos 6 Linux and nss-pam-ldapd

Tags: linux, ldap, pam

I am trying get centos 6 to authenticate against ldap (active directory to be specific) I am a bit confuse though because after installing nss-pam-ldapd I see several files that appear to be the same configuration. For example I have /etc/pam_ldap.conf and /etc/nslcd.conf. Both of these files seem to have the same configuration options. None seem to work. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Make sure you:
   1. yum remove sssd
   2. yum install openldap-clients nss-pam-ldapd
   3. Run Authconfig
   4. Check your /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
           - Check for your valid certfile is pointed to
   5. Check your /etc/nslcd.conf
           - confirm ssl start_tls
           - confirm certfile is pointing to a valid file

Here is a example authconfig line:

authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth \
   --ldapserver=ldap://ldap.example.com/,ldap://ldap2.example.com/ \
   --ldapbasedn=dc=example,dc=com  --update

Then make sure:
/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
TLS_CACERT /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
TLS_REQCERT demand


And in /etc/nslcd.conf:
ssl start_tls
tls_cacertfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
tls_reqcert never

So that you get a certificate not a empty directory.
```

Comment: This is the 'correct' method of conf file use according to the nss-pam-ldapd documentation. http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup . There are further configuration changes to make depending on your environment (such as TLS certificates for verification).

Answer (score 3):

While this has already been answered, there are few things to keep in mind:

- It is important to note that there is no need to disable sssd, as t[hat can connect to active directory](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.0_Release_Notes/security.html).
- You can also enable TLS and everything else in one shot with authconfig.

So to connect to LDAP, you would:

- Install pam_ldap, nss-pamd-ldapd and sssd (using yum to satisfy the dependencies) and enable sssd
- Copy the cert file into /etc/openldap/cacerts

Then in one shot, run this:

```
authconfig --enablesssd --enableldap --enableldaptls --ldapserver=ldap.example.com --ldapbasedn=dc=example,dc=com --enableldapauth --update
```

(authconfig will automatically pick up the cert residing in /etc/openldap/cacerts)

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the steps should be working.

if not use the TLS, just "ssl yes" is ok too

Must install these packages, cost me a lot of time to find out all these necessary packages on Redhat 6
nss-pam-ldapd
pam_ldap
openldap
openldap-clients

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I basically got this to work (except its sending passwords in clear text, I plan to fix this) so I figured I would share what I did.

I installed the nss-pam-ldap package using yum. I edited both pam_ldap.conf and nslcd.conf to reflect my environment. I then ran authconfig-tui answered its questions as best as I could. I did not turn on tls or ssl, just wanted to see if things were working. I ran "/etc/init.d/nslcd restart" and then I could su into ldap users as well as login with them via ssh. Then when I turned on ssl/tls it stopped working. And so I looked using TCP dump and grep-ed and found that my password was getting sent in clear text. So it works but I still need to get ssl/tls working. I would ldap client would send passwords already hashed but I guess not. Maybe there is a way to tell it what cypher to use to has before sending the password to ldap.

Any way I hope this helps others with this problem. Thanks

Comment: Transmitting pre-encoded passwords is a terrible idea because the directory server cannot enforce password quality without knowing the password, therefore all passwords should be sent in clear-text. Any directory server environment used for authentication, authorization, or other purposes where passwords must be transmitted should use TLS, or at the very least SSL.

Comment: Good point. In the end I configured krb5 to talk to AD which does not send passwords as plain text (as in they cant be easily read by any one listening on the network).